# Wait for other threads with same service to reach certain point

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multi-player networked game I am writing in Java, players connect to the server and are given 'cards' that they can play, each player has a service spawned in its own thread which handles everything.
What I am trying to do is work out a way for the server to be 'paused' until all players have connected and reach the same point in the service so the game can then start.

The server spawns threads like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numPlayers; i++){
    ArrayList<Card> playersCards = getPlayersCards(i-1);    
    Socket s = server.accept();
    System.out.println("Player "+ i +" connected.");
    Service service = new Service(s, playersCards);
    Thread t = new Thread(service);
    t.start();
}
```

And then my service:

```
public class Service implements Runnable {

    private Socket s;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;


    public Service(Socket aSocket, ArrayList<Card> cards) {
        s = aSocket;
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            out.println("Welcome to the Simple Stock Market Game.");
            out.flush();
            sendCards();
            //AT THIS POINT THE SERVICE WOULD NEED TO wait for all players to connect
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            out.println("Thanks for playing the Simple Stock Market Game.");
            out.flush();
        }
        try {
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Player disconnected."); 
    }

    private void sendCards() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String cardsJSON = gson.toJson(cards);
        out.println(cardsJSON);
        out.flush();    
    }

}
```

Now I assume I can pass the service how many players there are going to be, and wait for that many threads to reach that point?
Not really sure and hope you guys can help!

Comment: `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), which is exactly what you need.

Before your loop that create services, initialize it with the number of threads (players) expected:

```
CountDownLatch playersLatch = new CountDownLatch(numPlayers);
```

then in service:

```
playersLatch.countDown();
try {
    playersLatch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    //handle interruption
}
```

Also you might want to have a look at [java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), which is similiar but allows reuse after waiting threads are released.

Comment: The CyclicBarrier is reusable, but requires complicated synchronization to have only one thread call reset and only if no other is still waiting on the barrier. The Phaser is much easier to use for a reuse-case.

Answer (score 0):

If you call that repeatedly, a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) would be the best solution as it combines the CountDownLatch and CyclicBarrier in an easy and reusable way. For a one-time use the CyclicBarrier is enough (with a minor performance increase over the Phaser).

In addition keep in mind that if you use such a synchronization tool, that you unregister on error (in your final code), as otherwise all remaining parties would be stuck indefinitely.